# ReactJs throwing error importing svg files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

i'm facing a problem since updating to TypeScript 4.5.4 in ReactJS. Since my update the svg import doesn't work anymore, it's throwing the following error:

```
SyntaxError: unknown: Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can set `throwIfNamespace: false` to bypass this warning.
```

This is my corresponding svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 12000 12000" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
    <g id="Infinit" transform="matrix(49.0391,0,0,49.0391,500,2298.61)">
        <path d="M171.75,44.877C122.037,44.877 90.778,131.27 52.56,131.27C33.874,131.27 18.735,116.131 18.735,97.44C18.735,78.76 33.874,63.62 52.56,63.62C67.62,63.62 82.783,78.413 95.361,92.528L107.828,78.649C92.367,61.405 75.219,44.877 52.56,44.877C23.53,44.877 0,68.414 0,97.44C0,126.475 23.53,150 52.56,150C102.498,150 133.507,63.62 171.75,63.62C190.436,63.62 205.575,78.76 205.575,97.44C205.575,116.131 190.436,131.27 171.75,131.27C156.689,131.27 141.526,116.478 128.949,102.355L116.481,116.234C131.943,133.484 149.089,150 171.75,150C200.78,150 224.311,126.475 224.311,97.44C224.311,68.414 200.78,44.877 171.75,44.877Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear1);"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Circle-Pink" serif:id="Circle Pink" transform="matrix(49.0391,0,0,49.0391,500,2298.61)">
        <path d="M171.75,0.957C182.465,0.957 191.154,9.647 191.154,20.362C191.154,31.079 182.465,39.766 171.75,39.766C161.035,39.766 152.346,31.079 152.346,20.362C152.346,9.647 161.035,0.957 171.75,0.957Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear2);"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Cirlce-Orange" serif:id="Cirlce Orange" transform="matrix(49.0391,0,0,49.0391,500,2298.61)">
        <path d="M52.56,0.957C63.275,0.957 71.964,9.647 71.964,20.362C71.964,31.079 63.275,39.766 52.56,39.766C41.844,39.766 33.156,31.079 33.156,20.362C33.156,9.647 41.844,0.957 52.56,0.957Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear3);"/>
    </g>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="_Linear1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(224.311,0,0,224.311,0,75.4785)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(255,153,0);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(240,0,144);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="_Linear2" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(224.311,0,0,224.311,0,75.4785)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(255,153,0);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(240,0,144);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="_Linear3" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(224.311,0,0,224.311,0,75.4785)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(255,153,0);stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:rgb(240,0,144);stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I've imported it like this

```
import Brand from '../assets/brand.svg';
```

and used like this

```
          <img src={MBrand} style={{ height: "100px", width: "auto", marginRight: "15px" }} alt="Brand" />
```

The svg file was originally exporteb by Affinity Designer and i'll never had a problem with it. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: You should show the code you use to import and display your SVG, as well as any typings or config.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because of your webpack (or whatever bundler you're using that allows you to "import" SVGs). That `src` attribute is expecting a string, I think you are expecting the value of `Brand` to be data URL with the SVG contents base64 encoded in it. It seems tho that your bundler is giving you parsed XML data, ie. some kind of XML Document that react is struggling to use in the `src` attribute. Fix your bundler configuration.

```
console.log(Brand)
```